# UITextView: how to set the AttributedText with an empty String?

Tags: uitextview, iso

I have an UItextView and i set the AttributedText at the starting of the app so with en empty text because user didn't yet fill anything. The problem is that with an empty String the AttributedText seam to not apply for the new text i will enter. how to do ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no straight solution for that. Setting AttributedText with "" doesn't work.

However you can do easy fix:

```
if let text = field.attributedText?.string {
   //normal way
} else {
   field.font = ...
   field.fontColor = ...
   //sorry, no shadow and other nice tricks
}
```

Of course you could implement delegate to text field and adjust attributes when textFieldDidChange, but that doesn't work well with typing in Chinese language where letter can be composed from multiple characters so I couldn't use that.